# Android RecyclerView Adapter from Library module

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-libraries, adapter, aar

I create a local Android library with common shared code.
I successfully use and import it in my Android app project using the .aar file.

Now I create a custom RecyclerView Adapter in my library.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomFolderAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private Context context;
    private List<CustomObject> array_data;


    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List<CustomObject> array_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.array_data = array_data;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ...
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    ...
    }


    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txv1;

        private ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txv1 = v.findViewById(R.id.txv1);
        }
    }
}
```

Can I call it from my app's activity ?

Something like:

```
import static com.example.mycustomlibrary.MyCustomAdapter;
```

or

```
MyCustomLibrary().MyCustomAdapter
```

Comment: You can import it like any other class, what problem exactly are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to import it just like any other class - no `import static` needed, as long as it's a top-level class.  Just refer to it by the package name followed by the class name:

```java
import com.example.mycustomlibrary.MyCustomAdapter;
```